# Validate only parent XML element in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML like below,

```
<Message>
       <Header> <headerchild>child1</headerchild></Header>
       <Body><bodychild1>value1</bodychild1><bodychild2>value2</bodychild2></Body></Message>
```

In my XSD,I want to validate all the header elements.But only the  parent element has to be validated as a mandatory element.I dont want to validate the child elements inside .
Please help how to specify this in XSD.

Answer (score 0):

Use a repeatable skip wildcard as the content model of the parent.